# DNS not resolving though all keys are there in etcd?

Tags: kubernetes

Here are some details, and why this is important for my next step in testing:

- I can resolve any outside DNS
- etcd appears to have all keys updating
  correctly, along with directories (as expected)
- Local-to-Kubernetes DNS queries doesn't appear to be working against the etcd datastore,
  even though I can manually query for key-values.
- This is the next
  step that I need to complete before I can start using an NGINX L7 LB
  demo.

I looked
   at the advice in [#10265](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/10265#issuecomment-117267504) first [just in case], but it
   appears I do have secrets for the service account...and I think(?)
   everything should be there as expected.

The only thing I really see in the Kube2Sky logs are that etcd is found. I would imagine I should be seeing more than this?

```
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl logs kube-dns-v10-q9mlb -c kube2sky --namespace=kube-system
I0118 17:42:24.639508 1 kube2sky.go:436] Etcd server found: http://127.0.0.1:4001
I0118 17:42:25.642366 1 kube2sky.go:503] Using https://10.254.0.1:443 for kubernetes master
I0118 17:42:25.642772 1 kube2sky.go:504] Using kubernetes API 
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$
```

More Details:

```
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl exec -t busybox -- nslookup kubelab.local
Server: 10.254.0.10
Address 1: 10.254.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubelab.local'

error: error executing remote command: Error executing command in container: Error executing in Docker Container: 1

fedora@kubemaster ~]$ etcdctl ls --recursive
/kubelab.local
/kubelab.local/network
/kubelab.local/network/config
/kubelab.local/network/subnets
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.46.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.12.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.70.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.21.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.54.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.71.0-24
```

....and so on...the keys are all there, as expected...

Comment: as far as i know the DNS addon resolves services so that you can load balance to the pods behind. Did you setup a service for your pod? Can you `nslookup kubernetes` and resolve that?

Answer (score 2):

I see you changed the default "cluster.local" to "kubelab.local".  did you change the skydns config to serve that domain?

`kubectl exec --namespace=kube-system $podname -c skydns ps
PID   USER     COMMAND
    1 root     /skydns -machines=http://127.0.0.1:4001 -addr=0.0.0.0:53 -ns-rotate=false -domain=cluster.local.
   11 root     ps`

Note the `-domain` flag.

If that is correct, check that you passed correct `--cluster-dns` and `--cluster-domain` flags to Kubelet.  Then show me /etc/resolv.conf from a pod that can not do DNS lookups.

Comment: also the `kubernetes.local` DNS entry is supposed to be defined in the api-server SSL config when generating the cert. I am not sure it can be a problem but that would certainly be the last place one would check so I'll put it out there.